# JavaScript Drag & Drop API: which element was dragged?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I think I already know the answer to this, but I would like confirmation either way.

1. I have a number of draggable elements, not all of the same type.
2. I have a single drop target.
3. When I drag an element over the target, I would like to know which element was dropped onto it.

As far as I have read, the target element doesn’t get that information, so the only way is to set some sort of global (or closure) variable when in the `dragstart` event, and then use that variable at the other end:

```
var current=null;
function dragstart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='all';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text',this.innerHTML);
    current=this;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Another possibility is to set some arbitrary data to, say, the id of the element:

```
function dragstart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='all';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text',this.getAttribute('id'));
    current=this;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

but that is too indirect and a burden on naming things.

Is this truly the case, or is there a way the target can identify the element without all of this?

I need an answer it pure JavaScript (no libraries such as jQuery) please.

Thanks